# CASE statement with in SQL IN Condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, split

Input parameter contains a comma separated string.

```
DECLARE @FacilityCode VARCHAR(MAX) = 'a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i'
```

ID   |  Value

1    |   a

2    |   b

3    |   c

4    |   d

I need to query the matching data using the comma separated string.

> If `@FacilityCode = 'a,b'`
>   Table should return `a`,`b` as rows.
>
> If `@FacilityCode = ''`
>   Table should return all the rows

I am using the below query. It shows me syntax errors. Thanks for advance.

```
SELECT Value 
FROM Table
WHERE [GROUP] IN (CASE WHEN COUNT(SELECT Value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@FacilityCode,','))) = 0 
THEN '%%' ELSE (SELECT Value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@FacilityCode,',')) END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add `OR @FacilityCode = ''` to the where clause:

```
SELECT value
FROM t
WHERE @FacilityCode = '' OR EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@FacilityCode, ',') AS x
    WHERE x.[value] = t.[group]
)
```